# Identifying Metaphoric/Hyperbolic Hadith

Tags: hadith

Sometimes we read a hadith when Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) says with a metaphoric/hyperbolic style, like for example the sun prostates, sun sets in water, mind of women, etc

So how to identify whether the other hadith has the same style? It is important because some hadith are the basis for jurisprudence and rituals

Comment: In general, all hadith are taken literally unless there is proof that shows otherwise. So it's best to learn any hadith from scholars [who've studied the texts], not laymen.

Comment: @Muslimahياربالعالمين very good, do you have any recommended scholars for this issue?